# how to make textangulars insert html allow usage of iframe

Tags: angularjs

Textangular library uses angular-sanitize to sanitise text. I want to be able to insert iframe tags with youtube videos to support embedding videos.

How can I make angular-sanitize allow iframe tags?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Textangular but if you don't want Angular to sanitize you can use: [$sce.trustAsHtml()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)

Comment: don't do this if the iframe is part of user data or else you will have an xss vector

Answer (score 0):

TextAngular uses custom renderers to use a placeholder img while editing, then we convert it to an iFrame for display. See [how to strip placeholder img in textAngular editor in scope var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601385/how-to-strip-placeholder-img-in-textangular-editor-in-scope-var). Also we have a youtube button in the toolbar.