# Using textangular functions in angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I am new to *angular* and am trying to alter the default behavior of a *textangular* text input field on my site's backend (I am a guitarist, not a web developer, but can usually figure out what I need to do...). The field has an option to specify a youtube url and then *textangular* converts that to an image for purposes of editing in the backend. Then in front end *textangular* has means to have a youtube url displayed correctly as an iframe.

However, on the front end I am not using *angular* and I read that in my case, to get a youtube embed to show up in front end as iframe you have to use the *taApplyCustomRenderers* function.

For example, see here:

[how to strip placeholder img in textAngular editor in scope var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601385/how-to-strip-placeholder-img-in-textangular-editor-in-scope-var)

In my *angular* app, here are some of the relevant lines:

```
angular.module('dashboard')
.controller('EditController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

$scope.save = function () {
    $scope.busy = true;
    // I thoguht I could do this:
    $scope.somefield = taApplyCustomRenderers($scope.somefield);
    // then I would save to model
    });
```

I am getting error that *taApplyCustomRenderers* is undefined. I thought based on what I read that *taApplyCustomRenderers* is an available function when using *textangular* but being new to this I suppose I am missing some key step about injecting the function into the controller or something.

Hoping someone can shed some light.

Thanks in advance!
Brian

Comment: Angular is not the same as angularJS : although they share the same name, they have next to nothing in common. I am editing your tags so that you get more answers to your question (and I'll see if I can help too)

Comment: Are you saying you have a back-end made with Angular and a front-end not using Angular ? That's is very unclear in your question ...

Comment: Hi, yes in front end it is purely Laravel, pulling directly from the database for display, whereas in backend the textangular text editor I use to add my content is applying all sorts of sanitization for security reasons. Thanks! Brian

Comment: What exactly are you calling back-end and front-end ? To be clear, Angular (and AngularJS) are front-end frameworks in the sense that they are executed on the user's computer, not on the server (like PHP would). So do you mean "back-office" (second application to manage your data) instead of back-end ?

Comment: I meant back end as in the admin section of my website, where I enter guitar lesson material, and I meant front end as in what visitors see. thanks, Brian

Comment: Okay, it's clearer now, thank you ! In the code you have provided, there doesn't seem to be any declaration of `taApplyCustomRenderers`, would you mind posting your whole code ?

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the below post and sure enough all is working now! Thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TLDR;** When you try to access `taApplyCustomRenderers` you are recieving an error since it is not given to this current function, Inject the function and it will work.

### The Problem

While I have never actually tried using textAngular, let me explain what the problem is, and from there it should be easy to find the solution.

Your `EditController` is just a regular javascript function that gets run and attached to the relevant DOM element, so it only has access to functions that are declared in its own scope (or globally).

> Here is your exact code just indented differently so you can understand better:

```
angular.module('dashboard').controller(
    'EditController',
    [
        '$scope',
        '$http',
        '$location',
        '$routeParams', 
        function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
            ...
            $scope.somefield = taApplyCustomRenderers($scope.somefield);
        }
    ]
);
```

As you can see, the `controller function` has two parameters, the first being a `string` and the second an `array`, and the last `element` in the `array` is just a regular `function`.

### The solution

Checking the [textAngular documentation](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/wiki) I saw that the `taApplyCustomRenderers` is a factory, which means you can inject it into your controller function as so:

```
angular.module('dashboard').controller('EditController', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', 'taApplyCustomRenderers',
     function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, taApplyCustomRenderers) { 
         taApplyCustomRenderers(); // is now Available.
     }
    ]);
```

Comment: Ok, that makes a ton of sense! Works now!

Comment: Glad you enjoyed it. I always think it is better to give someone the tools to find the solution rather than just spoon-feed him...